# How can I remove the drop shadow that Chrome adds to elements that use overflow scroll?

Tags: scroll, webkit, overflow, css

I have an element that uses `overflow: scroll` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

It works great everywhere, but when scrolling up on the element, Chrome adds an inset box shadow to the element. I don't see it in any other browser.

Is there any way to get rid of that?

[image: box shadow on element with overflow scroll]

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

`-webkit-box-shadow: none;`

Comment: No, unfortunately not.